# How to open audio file from file manager and play that audio file using Flutter app

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I'm new in flutter development and I got stuck in a program where I want to play an audio file by selecting it from file manager.i am able to open audio file from file manager but I don't know how to play that audio file.
Please help me out with this.
I am using this code -

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FilePickerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FilePickerDemoState createState() => _FilePickerDemoState();
}
```

> I am using this for file picking and save file I want to know how to play save file

```
class _FilePickerDemoState extends State<FilePickerDemo> {
void _pickFiles() async {
_resetState();
try {
  _directoryPath = null;
  _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: _pickingType,
    allowMultiple: _multiPick,
    onFileLoading: (FilePickerStatus status) => print(status),
    allowedExtensions: ['mp3'],
  ))
      ?.files;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  _logException('Unsupported operation' + e.toString());
} catch (e) {
  _logException(e.toString());
}
if (!mounted) return;
setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
  _fileName =
  _paths != null ? _paths!.map((e) => e.name).toString() : '...';
  _userAborted = _paths == null;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio package to play audio.

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

final _player = AudioPlayer();
    

playAudio() async {
    try {
      await _player.setFilePath(widget.audioPath);
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
    _player.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another handy package is [AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) that can also cache local audio files.

Here is a very basic example, that has buttons to play, pause and stop a reference to local audio that is passed into a stateful widget, to get you started (based mainly off this Medium article) [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@pongpiraupra/a-comprehensive-guide-to-playing-local-mp3-files-with-seek-functionality-in-flutter-7730a453bb1a)

Reminder to save your audio in your local files like below

[image]

and add a reference in your yaml file and get dependencies

```
  assets:
    - assets/audio/
```

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioManagerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioManagerExample({required this.audioName, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String audioName;

  @override
  _AudioManagerExampleState createState() => _AudioManagerExampleState();
}

class _AudioManagerExampleState extends State<AudioManagerExample> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late AudioCache audioCache;

  @override
  void initState() {
    audioCache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);
    audioCache.load('audio/${widget.audioName}.mp3');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioCache.clearAll();
    audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              audioCache.play('audio/${widget.audioName}.mp3');
            });
          },
          child: Text('Play ${widget.audioName}'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              audioPlayer.pause();
            });
          },
          child: Text('Pause ${widget.audioName}'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              audioPlayer.stop();
            });
          },
          child: Text('Stop ${widget.audioName}'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```